# Magento 2.2 : MySQL General error 1787 when reindexing

Tags: database, magento2.2

How to fix the two errors below ?

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1787 When @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = 1, the statements CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can be executed in a non-transactional context only, and require that AUTOCOMMIT = 1., query was: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_index_eav_temp` LIKE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
```

My server in on Ubuntu 16.04 with Mysql 5.7.19 and php 7.0.24.

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?  What returns the mysql query : "SELECT @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY;" ?

Comment: I'm using "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper". The query returns "1".

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on the server. GTID is always-on server, please use below MySQL command to disable GTID. SET @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = OFF;
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = OFF_PERMISSIVE;

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162465)

Comment: did you find any solution, guys?

Answer (score 1):

Magento try to create a temporary table, but like you have ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY enable that failed.

> Only statements that can be logged using GTID safe statements can be logged when enforce-gtid-consistency is set to ON, so the operations listed here cannot be used with this option:
>
> - CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statements
> - CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE or DROP TEMPORARY TABLE statements inside transactions
> - Transactions or statements that update both transactional and nontransactional tables. There is an exception that nontransactional DML is allowed in the same transaction or in the same statement as transactional DML, if all nontransactional tables are temporary.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-gtids.html

I don't know if Magento 2 is able to work with GTID Consistency enable (seems not). If it's not a strong need, you can deactivate it.

Comment: How to disable it ?

Comment: Depends... Try to look for it in your my.cnf. You can have something like "enforce_gtid_consistency=true". Switch it to false and restart MySQL. Check if the modification is effective thanks to the query following:  "SELECT @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY;"

Comment: It is possible there are other configuration lines in you my.cnf about gtid, like gtid_mode (if it is, switch it to OFF). Don't forget to restart MySQL after a modification of my.cnf.

Comment: Actually, I can't switch off GTID on the RDS server I'm using, is there another way to clean the database from GTID stuffs ?

Comment: You can set values through MySQL. But if configurations are in my.cnf, these values will be reinitialized each time MySQL will restart. So its not a good way to do, but that let you test if the solution works. "SET @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = 1000;". Maybe a dump of the database before could be a good idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed by this module:
https://github.com/bangerkuwranger/Magento-2-GTID-Safe-URL-Rewrite-Tables